# bootstrap font-awesome can't work [using cdn]

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap and font-awesome.

The document says just importint CDN.

it is my simple codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<i class="fa fa-flag"></i> fa-flag
</body>
</html>
```

However, flag icon didn't appear.

Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: probably you have css but you need source of fonts, css only map icon from source file

Comment: i put it on an html file and was able to see the flag fine on my site. Do you have a link somewhere?

Comment: checkout this link,http://jsfiddle.net/Priyank57/c9mq7fba/

Comment: Ah, I guess it must be http access?

Comment: `cd path_to`

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`


later
http://0.0.0.0:8000/

It works!

Answer (score 0):

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

in

*EASIEST: BootstrapCDN by MaxCDN*

**point 2**

> Pat yourself on the back for your scalable-vector-icons-on-the-website
>   judo solution in a single line of code.

you need a source

css only mapping positions

I prefer this case

*EASY: Default CSS*

Answer (score 0):

If you're working locally you might need to add an "http:" in front of the CDN link. So try this instead:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```